# Bash, Using grep, sed or awk to extract section of text and then match

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a text file and want to extract all interfaces matching "blue"

---

```
random text random text random text 
random text random text 

int 1
    random text
    blue
    random text
    random text
int 2
    random text
    random text
    red
    random text
int 3
    random text
    random text
    random text
    blue
    random text
    random text
int 4
    blue
    random text
int n
    random text
    value
    random text

random text random text random text 
random text random text
```

---

Wanted output:

```
int 1
    blue
int 3
    blue
int 4
    blue
int n
    blue
```

(notice int 2 is "red" and therefore not displayed)

I've tried: grep "int " -A n file.txt | grep "blue" but that only display lines matching "blue". I want to also show the lines matching "int ". Also the section length can vary so using -A n hasn't been useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another sed solution

Will work for multiple blues

```
sed -n '/^int/{x;/blue/{p;d}};/blue/H' file
```

#### Input

```
random text random text random text
random text random text

int 1
    random text
    blue
    blue
    random text
    random text
int 2
    random text
    random text
    red
    random text
int 3
    random text
    random text
    random text
    blue
    random text
    random text
int 4
    blue
    blue
    blue
    blue
    blue
    random text
int n
    random text
    value
    random text

random text random text random text
random text random text
```

#### Output

```
int 1
    blue
    blue
int 3
    blue
int 4
    blue
    blue
    blue
    blue
    blue
```

Comment: nice, just assume like i should do just now for my post (testing your code) that paragraph are all in format *int ...*. You need to add the `^` as first cahr of  your `/int/` top avoid noise with other occurence that are not starting paragraph

Comment: @NeronLeVelu Editted :) Not sure if OP wants line is `blue` or contains `blue` or whatever so i have just left that as contains for now.

Comment: this was for `int` not for `blue` the *noise*.

Answer (score 2):

An awk solution could be the following:

```
awk '/^int/{interface = $0} /blue/{print interface; print $0}' input.txt
```

It always saves the latest discovered interface. If `blue` is found, it prints the stored interface and the line containing `blue`.

Comment: We overlapped!  I'll remove my comment

Comment: simple and accurate. I hate to use `sed` for anything more than `'s///'` construct.

Answer (score 1):

one possible GNU sed solution

```
sed -n '/^int\|blue/p' file | sed -r ':a; N; $! ba; s/int \w*\n(int)/\1/g; s/int \w*$//'
```

output

```
int 1  
    blue  
int 3  
    blue  
int 4  
    blue
```

Comment: try to avoid cascadind action (sed in this case) with pipe unless it is hard or ressource eating to make it in same tool.

Comment: Time is valuable resource. Feel free to give more simplified solution.

Comment: load content in buffer than use your loop (not *lite* but avoid pipe)

Comment: i understand, yes it will be wo pipe, however let it stay this way in answer, maybe am secretly in love with piping :)

Comment: @NeronLeVelu Simplified version in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/^int/ h
     /^[[:space:]]*blue/ {x;G;p;}
     d
     ' YourFile
```

- Assume there is 1 *blue* per paragraph and random text is not *int* or *blue* line
- one liner possible (but less explicit)

added (post) constraint

- paragraphe are all *int* started, no other (like *ext 1*, ...)

Explication:

- keep int line when occur in buffer
- when blue occur, add last line (exchance buffers, add 2 buffer, so header than blue), print result `{x;G;p;}`  (other action give the same depending of any other interest like `H;x;p` or `H;g;p`, in this case this is header destructive but it could be conservative using a `s///`)
- delete content (no printing and cycle to next line)

Comment: He assumed it does not.

Comment: @josifoski I have provided an answer for multiple blues.